# Given a multiple polygons what's the fastest way to find the one that accomodates all of them (it's guaranteed it exists)?

Tags: geometry

Given a multiple polygons what's the fastest way to find the one that accomodates all of them (it's guaranteed it exists)?

My current approach is:

1. For every polygon find max/min x and y coordinates (basically find the smallest rectangle, such that current polygon fits in).
2. Among all rectangle find the one with the largest area.
3. Return a corresponding polygon as an answer.

It works in *O(N)* time where *N* is the number of rectangles.

Comment: It is not clear to me either what your question is or how the proposed algorithm could be a solution for any of the possible interpretations of the question. Are the polygons fixed in the plane, and you're looking for a polygon which contains them all? Are they free to translate and rotate, and you're looking for a polygon which can contain them all under some transformation? Or is it something else?

Comment: Are the polygons fixed in the plane, and you're looking for a polygon which contains them all? -> Yes. I'm looking for a polygon that contains them all w/o any transformation. Polygons are not free to rotate, they're fixed in the plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that if the bounding polygon is convex, it is necessary and sufficient that it should contain all of the vertices of the input polygons. Let $P$ be the set of those vertices.

A simple bounding polygon is the axis-aligned rectangle, which I think you allude to: let $x_0 = \min(x : \exists (x,y) \in P)$, $x_1 = \max(x : \exists (x,y) \in P)$, $y_0 = \min(y : \exists (x,y) \in P)$, $y_1 = \max(y : \exists (x,y) \in P)$; and then the bounding axis-aligned rectangle is $(x_0, y_0) - (x_0, y_1) - (x_1, y_1) - (x_1, y_0)$.

A "better" bound (indeed, optimal in a certain sense) is the *convex hull* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull), [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvexHull.html)). There are many known algorithms, and their running times may depend on the size of the hull. If you want asymptotic optimality and reasonable simplicity, look at Chan's algorithm[1], although it requires other convex hull algorithms as subalgorithms.

Finally, let me note that it's still not clear to me that your algorithm is correct (consider the case where one of the polygons is $10\times 1$ rectangle, and the other is a $1\times 10$ rectangle), nor that it achieves the stated asymptotic complexity (which would require identifying the bounding rectangle of a polygon in $O(1)$ time).

[1] Timothy M. Chan. "Optimal output-sensitive convex hull algorithms in two and three dimensions". Disc. Comp. Geom. 16 (1996), pp.361–368

Comment: Thanks, but _it's guaranteed_ there's at least one 10x10 polygon besides these 2 then (i.e. we should return one of these polygon as the answer, there's no need to compute convex hull).